# How to detect android liveData state?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

First of all, I am new in LiveData.
I found this from the android official website.

> An exception to this behavior is that observers also receive an update
>   when they change from an inactive to an active state. Furthermore, if
>   the observer changes from inactive to active a second time, it only
>   receives an update if the value has changed since the last time it
>   became active.

I want to know how to detect the state.

```
   public void doLogin(View view){
        final LiveData<Pojo> liveData = loginViewModel.checkLoginAndgetUserData(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
        liveData.observe(LoginActivity.this, new Observer<Pojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Pojo pojo) {
                    Boolean isValid = loginViewModel.isValid(pojo);
                    if(isValid){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }
        });

    }
```

Here is my code. If Users first time failed to login and try to login again, that time `onChanged` method call without data changed. That time toast appears again. After sometime When network call completed then again `onChanged` method call.

Comment: a LiveData becomes inactive if it has no Active Observers. This means that if LifecycleOwner becomes `stopped`, then it is seen as `inactive`. So app being put to background makes the observers inactive.

Comment: There was a lake of my knowledge about live data. Now I am clear than before. Thanks.